# boost rtree of box gives wrong intersection with segment

Tags: c++, boost, r-tree, boost-geometry

Boost rtree gives wrong intersection result for some intersection with segment queries.
In this case the bounding box is a y-planar 10x10 square at y=0. I'm querying with a z-aligned line from (2, 1, 0) to (2, 1, 10). What's interesting is that if I use a box for query instead of a segment then it works as expected. This behavior is also present when the box is not planar, just move the min corner to (0, -5, 0) and it still happens.

Am I using this wrong or is it a bug in boost?

Edit: have tried this on Boost 1.56 and 1.59.

```
#include <vector>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;
typedef bg::model::point<double, 3, bg::cs::cartesian> point_def;
typedef bg::model::box<point_def> box;
typedef bg::model::segment<point_def> segment;
typedef std::pair<box, size_t> tri_box;
typedef bgi::rtree< tri_box, bgi::linear<8>> tree_type;

using namespace std;

TEST(boost_rtree, cant_intersect_box_with_segment) {
  vector<tri_box> buff(1);
  buff[0].first = box{point_def{0, 0, 0}, point_def{10, 0, 10}};
  buff[0].second = 1;
  tree_type tree(buff);

  segment query{point_def{2, 1, 0}, point_def{2, 1, 10}};
//  box query{point_def{2, 1, 0}, point_def{2, 1, 10}};
  vector<tri_box> out;

  size_t count = tree.query(bgi::intersects(query), back_inserter(out));

  ASSERT_EQ(0, count); // fails here
  ASSERT_EQ(0, out.size());
}
```

Edit: issue is being moved to boost mailing list: lists.boost.org/geometry/2015/09/3472.php

Comment: Yes, as sehe wrote this seems to be a bug in disjoint/intersects. As I wrote in the email on the list, you could create a ticket so you would get updates about this bug. Or if you'd like to contribute you could create a pull request with a fix on GitHub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As unlikely as it seems, this appears to me to be a bug.

The first version that even compiles this is Boost 1.56. All previous versions fail with

```
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG
    (
        false, NOT_OR_NOT_YET_IMPLEMENTED_FOR_THIS_GEOMETRY_TYPE
        , (types<Geometry>)
    );
```

But, even though the code is compiled, it does not seem to be correct...: the `intersects` call that underlies the query predicate itself returns "false positive" it seems.

Much simplified: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee9e3c0e0688ad50)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp>

namespace bg  = boost::geometry;

typedef bg::model::point<int, 3, bg::cs::cartesian> point;
typedef bg::model::box<point>     box;
typedef bg::model::segment<point> segment;

int main() {
    box y0rect = box{point{0, 0, 0}, point{10, 0, 10}};
    segment seg{point{2, 1, 0}, point{2, 1, 10}};

    bg::correct(y0rect);
    bg::correct(seg);
    assert(!bg::intersects(seg, y0rect));
}
```

**UPDATE**

Interestingly, it seems to work correctly ***sometimes*** for 2d. I'm not sure the outcome isn't simply undefined...

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50d160c840be24a3)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp>

namespace bg  = boost::geometry;

typedef bg::model::point<int, 4, bg::cs::cartesian> point;
typedef bg::model::box<point>     box;
typedef bg::model::segment<point> segment;

int main() {
    box y0rect = box{point{0, 0}, point{10, 10}};
    bg::correct(y0rect);

    {
        segment seg{point{12, 0}, point{20, 10}};
        bg::correct(seg);
        assert(!bg::intersects(seg, y0rect));
    }
    {
        segment seg{point{2, 0}, point{8, 6}};
        bg::correct(seg);
        assert(bg::intersects(seg, y0rect));
    }
    {
        segment seg{point{2, 0}, point{18, 6}};
        bg::correct(seg);
        assert(bg::intersects(seg, y0rect)); // OOPS BREAKS?
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Have raise the problem on the boost geometry mailing list.

Comment: Do you have a link to that? Would be very useful to add

Comment: Why did you not post the minimized version of the code? I subscribed now but I can't reply (because I didn't receive that message...). Maybe you can add something

Comment: @sehe Actually the assertion at line 23 fails, so the second one.

Comment: Fix should be released with Boost 1.61. You can also change the code in a way similar to this: https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/pull/332